# How to create iOS search bar animation with flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I wonder if there is any way to create this animation with flutter

[image]

Comment: You can achieve this by wrapping the search with a Hero widget, and transition to another screen.

Comment: @Mohammad thanks! I will try that!